# Error in installing Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, angular5

I'm a beginner for Ionic and getting mentioned error when i'm run the bellow code,

ionic start IonicShoppingList blank

```
Error: Cannot find module 'lodash._basecopy'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Denuka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\lodash._baseassign\index.js:9:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

I have installed node.js npm and ionic cordova.

What should i do to solve this ?

Comment: you don't have `lodash._basecopy`, you need install that module or You can try clearing your node_modules folder and trying again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to install lodash in the required folder.

If that folder has a package.json file, it is also best to add --save behind the install command.

`$ npm install lodash --save`

if the package.json file exists, and if it contains the lodash dependency you could try to remove the node_modules folder and run following command:

`$ npm cache clean`
`$ npm install`

The first command will clean the npm cache. (just to be sure) The second command will install all (missing) dependencies of the project.

I hope it helps.

Comment: @DenukaNirmalee I have updated the solution, Please try this. I hope it helps.